# Absolute import results in ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Python 3.6**

I've written some components and I'm trying to import one of them in the other.

Below is what my project structure looks like:

```
.
└── components
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── extract
    │   └── python3
    |       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── extract.py
    └── transform
        └── python3
            ├── __init__.py
            └── preprocess.py
```

**extract.py**

```
from components.transform.python3.preprocess import my_function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_function()
```

**preprocess.py**

```
def my_function():
    print("Found me")
```

When I run `python components/extract/python3/extract.py`

I see the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'components'

I've added an empty `__init__.py` file to the directories that contain modules as well as the top level package directory.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you tried, and what you mean by "with no success", but as far as I can see the problem is indeed the lack of any `__init__.py` files. Python thinks `components` is a module (that is, a `.py` file), you clearly want to treat it as a package (from which you can access modules using the `.` notation) - and to do that, it needs to contain an `__init__.py`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've added the `__init__.py` file to the directories with modules in them as well as the top level directory.

Comment: Which directory are you in when you run `python components/extract/python3/extract.py`? `"."`?

Comment: OK, thanks for updating the question. Main thing I see now is that the `transform` and `extract` directories are still lacking an `__init__.py`, so that I would expect the error now is "No module named 'transform'." What is the exact text of the error you now get?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for replying! The error is still "No module named 'components'"

Comment: @Alasdair I'm running it from the root of the project directory. So we are in a folder named etl_pipeline and the components folder is inside that.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I've always got around this by just calling all of that stuff from a file in the root folder. I'd make something like `run_extract.py`, and inside that it'd have `from components.extract.python3.extract import my_function`. I've just given up on dealing with individual files inside a module haha.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, imports require the top level package to be available in Python PATH (`sys.path`).

So to make it work, you should:

- cd to the directory containing `components`
- add `.` to the Python PATH:

  ```
  export PYTHONPATH='.'
  ```
- launch your script:

  ```
  python components/extract/python3/extract.py
  ```

On my system, it successfully displays:

```
Found me
```

Comment: Is this a permanent solution? It works when running it locally but would I need to do the same if it's run on a server for automated processes?

Comment: @JonathanPorter: for an automated process, the correct way would be to permanently put the directory containing components in the Python path (server side).

Comment: Thanks. `export PYTHONPATH='.'` solved my issue