# ModuleNotFoundError when running individual Python files with absolute imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, modulenotfounderror

> `ModuleNotFoundError` running Python 3.8.x

I'm building a python package containing classes and functions each with verbose tests. Inside the package I'm trying to use these building blocks to provide end-to-end uses and examples by using absolute imports at the top of these files (like in my tests).

The project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── examples
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── end_to_end_1.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test_useful_one.py
│       └── test_useful_two.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── useful_one.py
    └── useful_two.py
```

I'm running all tests from the package root using `python -m unittest tests/**/*.py`, and both test files contain absolute package imports from `utils` like so,

```py
from utils.useful_one import UsefulClass
```

this approach is succesful in running the tests and importing the `UsefulClass` class into the test files.

My issue arises when trying to use the same import statement inside the `examples/end_to_end_1.py` module and executing the file (again from the root of the package) using

```sh
python examples/end_to_end_1.py
```

Now I get a runtime `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.

In trying to follow the python language guidelines I'm trying to use absolute imports where possible but to no avail.

I have definitely misunderstood how the `__init__.py` files are supposed to tell the runtime where to resolve packages from. I don't think this use case is abnormal, since I see this same pattern inside node packages and ruby gems all the time.

#### Makeshift (Temporary) Solution

At the moment to solve this I have applied the solution from [Absolute import results in ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100236/absolute-import-results-in-modulenotfounderror) which, despite working, seems not too scalable when the repository is publically available and I feel like the Python ecosystem will have a solution for this issue. As Raymond Hettinger says, it feels like..

> There must be a better way!