# Why does my setup.py not update the python path correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, pythonpath, python-packaging

I have a Python package on GitHub (here is a [minimal example](https://github.com/erelsgl/setuptest/)). The folder structure is:

```
setuptest
+--- package1
+--- __init__.py
+--- +--- module1.py
+--- +--- main1a.py
+--- +--- main1b.py
+--- +--- __init__.py
+--- +--- 
+--- package2
+--- +--- module2.py
+--- +--- __init__.py
+--- demo1a.py
+--- demo1b.py
+--- setup.py
```

I have read elsewhere that it is best to use absolute imports everywhere, so in `demo1a.py` I do:

```
from setuptest.package1.module1 import func1
from setuptest.package2.module2 import func2
print ("func1", func1(), "func2", func2())
```

But running it gives an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptest'
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114511/827927) it is recommended to put the parent folder in PYTHONPATH, or put the directory containing components in the python library folder. But, as far as I understand, this should be done automatically by the setup procedure. So I ran

```
python3 setup.py install
```

but I still get the same error. Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages   # Always prefer setuptools over distutils
from codecs import open     # To use a consistent encoding
from os import path

setup(
    name='setuptest',  
    version='1.0', 
    description='Testing the setup procedure',
    url='https://github.com/erelsgl/setuptest',  # Optional
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[],         # Optional
)
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: That is the default behavior. If your project (library) is correctly installed then `import package` will just work. Am I missing misunderstanding the question? -- If it is installed correctly it is added to `sys.path` (no need to to add to `PYTHONPATH`).

Comment: what sinoroc said. Installing a package means copying (or linking) it to the executing python's `site_package` folder, which is the first place python looks when trying to resolve an import. All platforms should support this. Can you build a counter-example?

Comment: Yes, correction: upon installation of a distribution package, its importable packages are copied in the environment's `site-packages` directory, which is always listed in `sys.path`, so they are indeed importable. -- Aside: if you have to modify `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` yourself then it is a red flag to me, this should almost never be needed.

Comment: @sinoroc Here is a minimal example: https://github.com/erelsgl/setuptest I clone it from github, run `python3 setup.py install`, then run `python3 package/main1a.py` or `python3 package/main1b.py`, and get a ModuleNotFoundError. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without looking at the code, looks like you should use `python3 -m package.main1a` or `python3 -m package.main1b`. -- Those Python files that are part of an importable package, are not considered scripts anymore, they are executable modules. So you should use the `-m package.module` notation.

Comment: I get the same error. But maybe I should ask a separate question

Comment: Your ***top-level import packages*** seem to be `package1` `package2` and ***top-level import modules*** `demo1a` `demo1b`. So your absolute imports should start with those. For example `from package1.module1 import func1`. In other words the name of your ***distribution package*** (`setuptest`) is not relevant for imports. Also you might want to add `py_modules=['demo1a', 'demo1b']` to your `setup` call.

Comment: In case it helps: https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/packaging.html and https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/python_imports.html